# Passing user control object to another object as dependency property

Tags: silverlight

My xaml is as follows:

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="XXX" x:Name="mainMap"/>
<BingEditableMapControl:BingMapEditingControl BingMap="mainMap" />
```

For BingEditableMapControl, the property BingMap is a dependency property takes the control of Map. How do i pass the mainMap to the BingMap property through xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:-

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="XXX" x:Name="mainMap"/>
<BingEditableMapControl:BingMapEditingControl BingMap="{Binding ElementName=mainMap}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make mainMap a static resource and bind the BingMap property like this

BingMap={StaticResource mainMap}

Comment: how do i turn it into a resource? And its the map that is displaying that i want to be passed to the BingMapEditingControl

Comment: Add the following just under the <Window> tag
<Window.Resources>
  <m:Map CredentialsProvider="XXX" x:Key="mainMap"/>
</Window.Resources>

Comment: Hmm, that suggestion was stupid in this case, sorry ... Have you tried wrapping mainMap inside BingMap as a nested element like this
<BingEditableMapControl:BingMapEditingControl.BingMap>
   <m:Map CredentialsProvider="XXX" x:Name="mainMap"/>
</BingEditableMapControl:BingMapEditingControl.BingMap>